# OCaml Ctypes: allocate structure for out argument

Tags: ocaml, ctypes

I want to bind with `Ctypes` the following function ([ref.](https://developer.gnome.org/gi/stable/gi-GIConstantInfo.html#g-constant-info-get-value)) :

```
gint
g_constant_info_get_value (GIConstantInfo *info,
                           GIArgument *value);
```

I have defined the [GIArgument](https://developer.gnome.org/gi/stable/gi-common-types.html#GIArgument) structure in OCaml with the following :

**GTypes.mli** :

```
type argument_t
val argument: argument_t structure typ
val v_boolean: (bool, argument_t structure) field
val v_int8: (int, argument_t structure) field
val v_uint8: (Unsigned.uint8, argument_t structure) field
val v_int16: (int, argument_t structure) field
val v_uint16: (Unsigned.uint16, argument_t structure) field
val v_int32: (int32, argument_t structure) field
val v_uint32: (Unsigned.uint32, argument_t structure) field
val v_int64: (int64, argument_t structure) field
val v_uint64: (Unsigned.uint64, argument_t structure) field
val v_float: (float, argument_t structure) field
val v_double: (float, argument_t structure) field
val v_short: (int, argument_t structure) field
val v_ushort: (Unsigned.ushort, argument_t structure) field
val v_int: (int, argument_t structure) field
val v_uint: (Unsigned.uint, argument_t structure) field
val v_long: (Signed.long, argument_t structure) field
val v_ulong: (Unsigned.ulong, argument_t structure) field
val v_ssize: (PosixTypes.ssize_t, argument_t structure) field
val v_size: (PosixTypes.size_t, argument_t structure) field
val v_string: (string, argument_t structure) field
val v_pointer: (unit Ctypes_static.ptr option, argument_t structure) field
```

**GTypes.ml** :

```
type argument_t
let argument : argument_t structure typ = structure "GIArgument"
let v_boolean = field argument "v_boolean" (bool)
let v_int8 = field argument "v_int8" (int8_t)
let v_uint8 = field argument "v_uint8" (uint8_t)
let v_int16 = field argument "v_int16" (int16_t)
let v_uint16 = field argument "v_uint16" (uint16_t)
let v_int32 = field argument "v_int32" (int32_t)
let v_uint32 = field argument "v_uint32" (uint32_t)
let v_int64 = field argument "v_int64" (int64_t)
let v_uint64 = field argument "v_uint64" (uint64_t)
let v_float = field argument "v_float" (float)
let v_double = field argument "v_double" (double)
let v_short = field argument "v_short" (short)
let v_ushort = field argument "v_ushort" (ushort)
let v_int = field argument "v_int" (int)
let v_uint = field argument "v_uint" (uint)
let v_long = field argument "v_long" (long)
let v_ulong = field argument "v_ulong" (ulong)
let v_ssize = field argument "v_ssize" (PosixTypes.ssize_t)
let v_size = field argument "v_size" (size_t)
let v_string = field argument "v_string" (string)
let v_pointer = field argument "v_pointer" (ptr_opt void)
let () = seal argument
```

Then here is the implementation of the function :

**GIConstantInfo.mli** :

```
val get_value:
  t structure ptr -> GITypes.argument_t structure ptr
```

**GIConstantInfo.ml**

```
let get_value info =
  let get_value_raw =
    foreign "g_constant_info_get_value"
      (ptr constantinfo @-> ptr GITypes.argument @-> returning int) in
  let arg_ptr = allocate_n GITypes.argument ~count:1 in
  let _ = get_value_raw info arg_ptr in
  arg_ptr
```

and the test :

```
  let test_get_value test_ctxt =
    constant_test (fun info ->
        let type_info = GIConstantInfo.get_type info in
        match GITypeInfo.get_tag type_info with
        | GITypes.Int32 -> let argument = GIConstantInfo.get_value info in
          let value = getf (!@argument) GITypes.v_int32 in
          assert_equal_int 511 (Int32.to_int value)
        | _ -> assert_equal_string "The tag should be " "Int32"
      )
```

The problem is that I am not able to get the 511 value, I have 0 (I tested this in another language so I am sure of the value I should obtain). I don't know what is wrong :

- is it the OCaml structure construction ?
- is it the allocation of the structure ?
- is it the function binding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the Gtk+ documentation was not really clear, the `GIArgument` is not a `structure`, it is an `union` defined in *gitypes.h* .

```
union _GIArgument
{
  gboolean v_boolean;
  gint8    v_int8;
  guint8   v_uint8;
  gint16   v_int16;
  guint16  v_uint16;
  gint32   v_int32;
  guint32  v_uint32;
  gint64   v_int64;
  guint64  v_uint64;
  gfloat   v_float;
  gdouble  v_double;
  gshort   v_short;
  gushort  v_ushort;
  gint     v_int;
  guint    v_uint;
  glong    v_long;
  gulong   v_ulong;
  gssize   v_ssize;
  gsize    v_size;
  gchar *  v_string;
  gpointer v_pointer;
};
```

Since `Ctypes` handles `union` in almost the same way than `structure` I was able to make it works with :

**GTypes.mli** :

```
type argument_t
val argument: argument_t union typ
val v_boolean: (bool, argument_t union) field
val v_int8: (int, argument_t union) field
val v_uint8: (Unsigned.uint8, argument_t union) field
val v_int16: (int, argument_t union) field
val v_uint16: (Unsigned.uint16, argument_t union) field
val v_int32: (int32, argument_t union) field
val v_uint32: (Unsigned.uint32, argument_t union) field
val v_int64: (int64, argument_t union) field
val v_uint64: (Unsigned.uint64, argument_t union) field
val v_float: (float, argument_t union) field
val v_double: (float, argument_t union) field
val v_short: (int, argument_t union) field
val v_ushort: (Unsigned.ushort, argument_t union) field
val v_int: (int, argument_t union) field
val v_uint: (Unsigned.uint, argument_t union) field
val v_long: (Signed.long, argument_t union) field
val v_ulong: (Unsigned.ulong, argument_t union) field
val v_ssize: (PosixTypes.ssize_t, argument_t union) field
val v_size: (PosixTypes.size_t, argument_t union) field
val v_string: (string, argument_t union) field
val v_pointer: (unit Ctypes_static.ptr option, argument_t union) field
```

**GTypes.ml** :

```
type argument_t
let argument : argument_t union typ = union "GIArgument"
let v_boolean = field argument "v_boolean" (bool)
let v_int8 = field argument "v_int8" (int8_t)
let v_uint8 = field argument "v_uint8" (uint8_t)
let v_int16 = field argument "v_int16" (int16_t)
let v_uint16 = field argument "v_uint16" (uint16_t)
let v_int32 = field argument "v_int32" (int32_t)
let v_uint32 = field argument "v_uint32" (uint32_t)
let v_int64 = field argument "v_int64" (int64_t)
let v_uint64 = field argument "v_uint64" (uint64_t)
let v_float = field argument "v_float" (float)
let v_double = field argument "v_double" (double)
let v_short = field argument "v_short" (short)
let v_ushort = field argument "v_ushort" (ushort)
let v_int = field argument "v_int" (int)
let v_uint = field argument "v_uint" (uint)
let v_long = field argument "v_long" (long)
let v_ulong = field argument "v_ulong" (ulong)
let v_ssize = field argument "v_ssize" (PosixTypes.ssize_t)
let v_size = field argument "v_size" (size_t)
let v_string = field argument "v_string" (string)
let v_pointer = field argument "v_pointer" (ptr_opt void)
let () = seal argument
```

**GIConstantInfo.mli** :

```
val get_value:
  t structure ptr -> GITypes.argument_t union ptr
```

**GIConstantInfo.ml**

```
let get_value info =
  let get_value_raw =
    foreign "g_constant_info_get_value"
      (ptr constantinfo @-> ptr GITypes.argument @-> returning int) in
  let arg_ptr = allocate_n GITypes.argument ~count:1 in
  let _ = get_value_raw info arg_ptr in
  arg_ptr
```

TL;DR: It was an `union` , I just had to replace *structure* by *union*.